# Вопрос по venv (виртуальное окружение)

Tags: python-3.x, django

Не получается активировать venv через import os

Проблема

```
import os

os.system('python -m venv venv')
os.system('source venv/bin/activate')
os.system('pip install django')
```

и под venv использовать pip или django-admin start project
Как сделать так что бы os ог с окружением работать?

Comment: Никак не сделать. Функция `system` запускает процесс вообще без какого-либо окружения и после её завершения процесс полностью уничтожен. Команды, выполняемые в нескольких вызовах `system`, никак между собой не связаны и друг на друга не влияют.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev есть альтернативные способы чтобы достичь цель?

Comment: Я бы рекомендовал сначала разобраться с принципами работы виртуальных окружений, чтобы понимать причины бесполезности `system` и поиска подходящих вам решений. Возможно, удастся приспособить модуль [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev ок, спасибо.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev все решил проблему с .sh

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен, но с хитростями. 
Хочу поделиться с ответом, может кому то поможет.

Что бы получить доступ к окружению нужно создать .sh файл

Но все делается в питоне
Пример

```
sh = """
source venv/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
django-admin startproject core . 
"""


with open('requirements.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as text:
    text.write("asgiref==3.2.5\nDjango==3.0.4\nPillow==7.0.0\npsycopg2==2.8.4\npytz==2019.3")

os.system('python -m venv venv')
with open('act.sh', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as text:
    text.write(sh)
os.system('bash act.sh')
```

Ну а потом можете удалить shell файл

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev  Я достиг цели, но так правильно?